# Why does Vim always manage to clip off at least a couple of characters when copying and pasting?

Tags: vim, text

Vim always manages to clip off at least of couple of characters when I copy something from a text file, such as a public rsa key for example.

Generally, I open a text file in my computer, highlight the text, copy it to my clipboard. I go into my terminal (with Vim already open) and then:

```
i (for insert)
ctrl+shift+v
```

Am I doing something wrong?

I've double checked, and triple checked, this, and I am absolutely sure that I highlighted all of the text that I needed to copy. Other times it works fine. There does not seem to be any consistency in regards to when it happens.

Anyone experience this?

Comment: How are you copying things?

Comment: Can you paste an example of what exactly you're copying and how?

Comment: Sorry guys, I added an example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens because something in the pasted text triggers a key mapping unexpectedly. This is what paste mode is for.

Do this before pasting:

```
:set paste
```

And turn it off after:

```
:set nopaste
```

This can be annoying to type frequently, so there is a way to map it to a key combination. I use `,p` for this, and have this in my .vimrc:

```
set pastetoggle=,p
```

(Yes, I use an actual comma here, not `<Leader>`. That's because `<Leader>` won't work here, as this isn't technically a mapping.)

This is a toggle, so you can use it to turn the mode on and off. It works in both normal mode and insert mode.

You do want to turn it off after the paste. Since paste mode disables your insert mappings, you don't want to leave it on all the time.

You can read more about the paste option with `:help 'paste`.

Answer (score 1):

The annoyance of toggling to and form paste mode can be avoided by using "+p or "*p. (You're putting the quoteplus register).

More often than not, I prefer "+P, since this leaves my cursor at the end of properly formatted put. see :help quoteplus for details. So the whole workflow is:

```
outside of vim: copy to clipboard
inside of vim: "+P
```